# Trouble with char* and char** (C --> C++)

Tags: c++, c, pointers, char

Okay, I am trying to integrate some C code into a C++ project, and have run into a few problems. I will detail the first one here.

I keep running into this error:

error: cannot convert 'char*' to 'char**' in assignment|

here is the offending code (with the breakpoint marked):

```
char** space_getFactionPlanet( int *nplanets, int *factions, int nfactions )
{
   int i,j,k;
   Planet* planet;
   char **tmp;
   int ntmp;
   int mtmp;

   ntmp = 0;
   mtmp = CHUNK_SIZE;
   tmp = malloc(sizeof(char*) * mtmp); <--- Breakpt
```

The malloc function is derived from a C header. Here is the declaration:

```
_CRTIMP void* __cdecl __MINGW_NOTHROW    malloc    (size_t) __MINGW_ATTRIB_MALLOC;
```

I am using codeblocks, which is set to use MinGW. The above syntax is totally foreign to me.

I am totally stumped, since this code works fine in the C program I took it from.

Any Ideas?

EDIT 1:

Oops, just realized that the declaration is from stdlib.h.

EDIT 2:

I tried:

```
tmp = static_cast<char **>(malloc(sizeof(char*) * mtmp));
```

As suggested, but not I get error: invalid static_cast from type 'char*' to type 'char**'.

EDIT 3:

Okay, reinterpret_cast works, but the solution to replace mallocs seems much more elegantly simple, so I am going with that.

However, there is no free(tmp) at the end of the function. Is this a problem if I don't put in a delete tmp[]?

**EDIT 4: I should add that tmp is returned by the function, so it is neccesary to delete tmp, or is this automatic?**

Okay I am marking this solved. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Your description of the problem does not appear to be accurate. `malloc` returns `void *`. It cannot produce an error message about conversion from `char *` to `char **`. Ancient version of `malloc` specification used to return `char *`, but you claim that the one you are using returns `void *`. This just doesn't look accurate. Either you are incorrectly identifying the erroneous line, or there's another `malloc` in the program, not the one you think is being used.

Comment: There is a realloc line that does that, but yeah, its really weird. It specifically says char* to char**. Maybe I messed up stdlib.h.

Comment: No, it isn't changed. Bizzare, but avoided, thankfully.

Comment: Do a global search through the source code and the library headers for `malloc` declarations. Maybe someone wrote "their own" `malloc` or somehow managed to include some old standard headers in addition to the normal ones.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're converting to C++, then let's do away with the malloc shall we?

```
tmp = new char*[mtmp];
```

But later on, you will probably find something like this:

```
free(tmp);
```

Which you need to change to this:

```
delete [] tmp;
```

If tmp is returned from the function, do not delete it.  You need to trace the pointer.  Somewhere, perhaps in multiple locations, free is going to be called.  You need to replace that with delete if you are going with this solution.  However, an even better solution would be to ditch the pointers all together, and replace it with a

```
vector<string>
```

Comment: Bless you! Malloc seems unnecessarily annoying.

Comment: Actually, in this function, there is no free(tmp), but there is: tmp = realloc(tmp, sizeof(char*) * mtmp);

Comment: Thanks. I have a  question about realloc, but I'll save that for another post.

Answer (score 5):

C++ is not so free with pointer type conversions. You will have to do something like this:

```
tmp = static_cast<char **>(malloc(sizeof(char *) * mtmp));
```

That will work if your `malloc()` returns a `void*`. However, the errors you're getting indicate that your `malloc()` is declared to return a `char*`, and in this case you'd have to use `reinterpret_cast` instead:

```
tmp = reinterpret_cast<char **>(malloc(sizeof(char *) * mtmp));
```

This casts the return type of `malloc()` to a type suitable for assignment into `tmp`. You can read more about the different types of casts in C++ at [Type Casting](http://cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/typecasting/).

Note that if this code must still compile in C, you can use a C-style cast instead:

```
tmp = (char **)malloc(sizeof(char *) * mtmp);
```

Comment: I don't really care about backward compatibility.

Comment: Also, what exactly is that code doing? Is it changing the pointer to a 'char' into a pointer to a pointer to a char?

Comment: Tried the first block of code, and it now says invalid static_cast from type 'char*' to type 'char**'

Comment: @Biosci3c: try `reinterpret_cast` instead of `static_cast`. I'll change the answer.

Comment: Bingo, works fine. However, replacing mallocs seems like a more elegant solution.

Comment: `static_cast` should work fine for converting from `void*` (and should be preferred).  It sounds like Biosci3c's `malloc` has a non-standard prototype that returns `char*` instead of `void*`, however.

Answer (score 2):

[`malloc(3)`](http://www.manpagez.com/man/3/malloc/) returns `void*`, which could be assigned to any other pointer type in C, but not in C++. This is one of the places where C++ is not backward-compatible with C. You can either do what other posters said - cast it to `char**`, or go all the way to proper C++ [free store usage](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/dynamic/) with operators `new[]` and `delete[]`:

```
char** tmp = new char*[mtmp]; // was malloc(sizeof(char*) * mtmp);
// ... use tmp
delete [] tmp; // was free( tmp );
```

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps a cast is in order:

```
tmp = static_cast<char **>(malloc(sizeof(char*) * mtmp));
```

Comment: `static_cast` is preferable to `reinterpret_cast` when converting to/from `void*`.

Comment: @jamesdlin: Thank you for pointing that out. I've changed the answer to avoid spreading bad information.

Answer (score 1):

Change `tmp = malloc(sizeof(char*) * mtmp);` to:

```
 tmp = (char**)malloc(sizeof(char*) * mtmp);
```

And don't go around changing malloc's to new's, as some have wrongly suggested, because of two reasons:

1) its not broken, so don't fix it (!)

2) you could introduce subtle or flat out horrible bugs that will eat away hours of your life later on.

Do spend your time fixing broken code, not code that works...

Comment: My friend, I think you are going to get flamed, considering the above answers :P

Comment: I understand that I could "make it work," but the vector approach seems more streamlined.

Comment: What do you mean? You just wanted to get the code to compile, all you need is a cast. If that code resizes the array up, though, and works with a high enough array, something like vector might be better. Personally, I would just add the cast and call it a day.

Comment: Even though I suggested switching to use new/delete, that was before I knew that he returned the array from the function.  So I would actually agree with you on that.  I would however, approve an update to use a vector of strings, even though it might be a lot of work.  Since the compiler obviously won't allow him to call free or realloc on a vector, the bugs should be easy to find.

Comment: I'm overly aggresive from quitting smoking recently... sory :P